# Controller override issue Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, customer-account, fatal-error

I am trying to override customer/account/editpost controller.

I am getting error

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context

I created di.xml file at location `module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

   <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost" 
     type="Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Index\Editpost" />
</config>
```

and controller `Controller\Index\Editpost.php`

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Index;

class Editpost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost
{

    public function execute()
    {

        echo "asdasdsda"; die;
        return parent::execute();
    }


}
```

Comment: Remove `var/generation` and try again.

Comment: still not working whole site broke

Comment: Try to refresh the page many times?

Comment: I want to override customer/account/editpost controller.  I refreshed site many time .

Comment: still getting the same error? Try to clear Magento cache and remove `return parent::execute();` in your execute method.

Comment: Thanks Khoa,  After clearing cache, and running upgrade and compilation, it worked after some time.

Comment: Yeash site and overriding both are working now :) Thanks again

Comment: convert your comment into your answer @KhoaTruongDinh so charan can accept it :)

Comment: I have posted 1 more question, can you help me there as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- The main reason is that the Controller classes are generated (automatically) in **var/generation** folder. Please, delete this folder.
-- Make sure the Magento Cache is clear.

**Note:** May we need to refresh the browser again again because the generation classes need time to re-generate.